# Input scores and count the average

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am so new to JavaScript even though I know that it should be pretty easy, so please help!
I know that there were some similar topics but I need to use this template

here is my assignment:

Allow the user to input seven different scores
Compute the average of all those scores
Display the average on the screen

[image]

What I have so far:

```
// init vars, get input from user
var scores = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

score[0] = (prompt("Type in a Score 1 of 7") )
score[1] = (prompt("Type in a Score 2 of 7") )
score[2] = (prompt("Type in a Score 3 of 7") )
score[3] = (prompt("Type in a Score 4 of 7") )
score[4] = (prompt("Type in a Score 5 of 7") )
score[5] = (prompt("Type in a Score 6 of 7") )
score[6] = (prompt("Type in a Score 7 of 7") )

function calculate() {
    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        total += score[i];
    }
    average = (total / scores.length).toFixed(2);
}

function getscores() {
    while (scores.length < 7) {
        scores.push(parseInt(prompt("Please input a score")));
    }
}

getScores();
calculate();
showScores();

function showScores() {
    document.write("The average of those scores is: " + average);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what went wrong?

Comment: Need help with what, exactly? We can't provide any assistance unless you tell us what problem(s) you're encountering, such as what errors you're seeing, or unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You should define `total` with `var` and assign in to `0`:

```
 function calculate() {
   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
     total += scores[i];
   }
    average = (total / scores.length).toFixed(2);
 }
```

Also you should set `average` global just like you did with scopes:

```
var average;
```

Comment: Also  "score" is undefined

Comment: @BrendanScarvell, what do you mean, `score` is undefined?

Comment: @Brendan Scarvell : i think that it is OP's typo.updated my answer

Comment: @Atutouato : He means that there is an array `scores`, but OP is using  an array `score`in the `for` loop.

Comment: He's using score as an array at the top with out it being defined as an array, which would throw `ReferenceError`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var score = [];

function getScores() {
    while (score.length < 7) {
        score.push(parseInt(prompt("Please input a score")));
    }
}

function calculate() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        total += score[i];
    }
    average = (total / score.length).toFixed(2);
}

function showScores() {
    alert("The average of those scores is: " + average);
}

getScores();
calculate();
showScores();
```

**[Working JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/DGqvY/)**